# Group generated by two reflections order 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetry, reflection

I have two reflections $r$, $s$ with $r^{2}=s^{2}=e$.
Also $rs \neq sr$ and $(rs)^4 = (sr)^4= e$.

I know $r$ and $s$ generate a group of order $16$ but that was by writing each matrix multiplication by hand. I wanted to know if there was a simpler way of finding the order.

I thought maybe it has something to do with dihedral group $D_{16}$ but the condition $rsr^{-1} = s^{-1}$ is not satisfied with the reflections I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a presentation for the dihedral group of order 8. $rs$ is your generating rotation, and you can check that it is inverted by conjugation by $r$ or $s$. There are a few other details to check...

Note that two distinct involutions always generate a dihedral group of order twice the order of their product. (Possibly infinite.)

Comment: thanks so $<rs, r>$ generate a group of order $8$ and so does $<sr,s>$, so the group generated by $<r,s>$ is of order $16$?

Comment: Nope, $\{rs,r\}$, $\{sr,s\}$ and $\{r,s\}$ all generate the same group, of order $8$. That they generate the same group is obvious since, for example, $s=r^{-1}rs$ hence $s\in\langle rs,r\rangle$.